# Situps are being a pain even though my abs aren't sore anymore

Tags: abdominals

TLDR at the bottom

So whenever I attempt to do a situp it is absurdly difficult for me. With my legs straight instead of bent it is slightly easier but still difficult. However 2 weeks ago on Thursday I started a conditioning program with weights. The following Monday was Core workout day and I was late by 35 minutes and had to super-set all of it. This was the first time I had worked my core like that. I caught up with everyone and finished with them in 15 minutes. My core was sore the rest of the week until Monday. (Because of Thanksgiving conditioning was canceled this week.)

TLDR
Before the core workout day I could pump out situps with ease. But now I can hardly do them.  Are my abdominal muscles still recovering even though they're not sore?

Comment: Is anyone able to answer?

Comment: Are you _now_ able to do sit-ups with ease?  Perhaps you can edit the question, or write or accept an answer.

Answer (score -1):

So I am not entirely sure I understand what you're asking. You may have over-trained initially which could lead to an increased recovery time. So typically what I would recommend would be that you make sure you have sufficient protein intake. I would also recommend stretching your core with something like yoga would help. I would highly recommend upward facing dog. If you don't have a place to take a class I would suggest either Nike Training Club or YouTube to find routines.